# How to use labels with Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

Bootstrap 3 used to have [labels](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_labels.htm). I need to update to Bootstrap 5. How to use labels with this current version considering that labels do not exist anymore? How to get them back? Maybe there is a replacement?

With Bootstrap 3 it used to work like this:

```css
<span class = "label label-default">Default Label</span>
<span class = "label label-primary">Primary Label</span>
<span class = "label label-success">Success Label</span>
<span class = "label label-info">Info Label</span>
<span class = "label label-warning">Warning Label</span>
<span class = "label label-danger">Danger Label</span>
```

Results in:
[image]

But with Bootstrap 5 there is no `label` class whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Like always, once written down the question I find the [answer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#labels-and-badges):

> Renamed `.label` to `.badge` to disambiguate from the `<label>` element.

So the wanted docs is here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/badge/